# Need help with numerical solution of a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
eqns = 
  {Derivative[4][f][y] - 2 Derivative[2][f][y] a^2 + a^2 (-r y + a^2) f[y] == 0,
   y = 0, 
   f[y] == 0,
   Derivative[3][f][y] - Derivative[1][f][y] a^2 == 0,
   Derivative[1][f][y] == 1,
   Derivative[2][f][y] == γ};

sol[r_?NumericQ, γ_?NumericQ] :=
  NDSolve[eqns, {f}, {y, 0, 100}, 
    Method -> "BDF",
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
    InterpolationOrder -> All,
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Off[ReplaceAll::reps];
a = 5;

Plot[Evaluate[{y = 1, f[y] = 0, f''[y] = 0} /. sol], {y, 0, 50}]
```

How can I solve this problem. I have to find `R` in the plot

Comment: Load editable code, not picture

Comment: ok thanks will do it

Comment: What is the point of having `Off[ReplaceAll::reps];`? It disables the message that indicates a possible cause of trouble (to wit, that `sol` has no use as a replacement because it is not evaluating to a `Rule` or `List` thereof).

Comment: I've said this before: `Off[]` and `Quiet[]` are convenient ways of lying to yourself that your code works.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[y, eqns, sol]

eqns[a_?NumericQ,
   r_?NumericQ, γ_?
    NumericQ] := {Derivative[4][f][y] - 2 Derivative[2][f][y] a^2 +
     a^2 (-r y + a^2) f[y] == 0, f[0] == 0,
   Derivative[3][f][0] - Derivative[1][f][0] a^2 == 0,
   Derivative[1][f][0] == 1, Derivative[2][f][0] == γ};

sol[a_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, γ_?NumericQ] :=
 NDSolveValue[eqns[a, r, γ], f, {y, 0, 100}, Method -> "BDF",
  MaxSteps -> Infinity, InterpolationOrder -> All]

eval = sol[1, 2, 3];
```

Now can do:

```
Plot[eval[y], {y, 0, 5}]
```

I would recommend not going to 50 because of the extreme rate of growth. Alternatively, do a log plot.

Comment: thanks a lot,if i would like to find the value of R how i can do it?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What values are you given, such that you then might compute `r`? (I assume you mean `r` because there is no `R` anywhere in sight.)

Comment: excuse me,yes i mean r,because in this problem I can  set the value of a and find r and the plot (r,a) thanks again and excuse for me for my english sir

Comment: 'a' i fixed value ,could be (0,1,2,3...)

i have to resolve this equation and find the plot of (a,r) with this condition y=1 -> f[y]=0,f''[y]=0

Thanks and sorry for my bad english :/